# Remove span class through regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, html, css

I have big file catering to 1000+ span class for pagenumbers. I would like to remove the complete syntax with the text in notepad++ through a ReGex. Example,`<p>Cillacepro di to tem endelias eaquunto maximint eostrum eos dolorit et laboria estiati<span class=”pagenum”><a name=”Page_4” id=”Page_4”>[Pg 4]</a></span>Cillacepro di to tem endelias</p>`

I would to replace `<span class=”pagenum”><a name=”Page_4” id=”Page_4”>[Pg 4]</a></span>` with " " such that it finds the pattern for two and three digits, as well. I am new to this regex string search therefore, I would be grateful if anyone could help me with a replace string for the same.
Regards,
Aman Mittal

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to find and what you want to replace it with, so I suggest you look at [this tutorial](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I am simply trying to replace <span class=”pagenum”><a name=”Page_4” id=”Page_4”>[Pg 4]</a></span> with a space. I am looking for a regex search string that that remove all the page numbers at once so that I don't have to manually remove each syntax one by one.

Comment: I imagine that matching `<span class="pagenum">.*?</span>` will be sufficient, as only this span class is likely to contain the page number data you want to eliminate. Note that `.*?` will match the minimum number of arbitrary characters, ensuring the that the `</span>` in the match is paired with the same leading `<span ...>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out the time and providing a solution. It worked wonders for me. I am too grateful to you. Thanks a lot! Stay blessed!

Comment: @AFH I wish I could like your profile and let everyone know how great of a person you are. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AFH: I am sorry to trouble you again. But in my project, I cam across another type of page number span: <span class="tei tei-pb" id="page001">[pg 001]</span><a name="Pg001" id="Pg001" class="tei tei-anchor"></a>  I tried this code to find them all at once: <span class="tei tei-pb" id="page\d+">[pg \d+\]</span><a name="Pg\d+" id="Pg\d+" class="tei tei-anchor"></a> However, it does not seem to work. Could you please let me know the errors in the regex search? I would be highly obliged to you.

Comment: Also, If I would like to search for roman number - i, ii, iii... in the same regex then how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would like to thank @AFH for providing generic answer which could cater to Page, Pg and other types as well. 
I imagine that matching `<span class="pagenum">.*?</span>` will be sufficient, as only this span class is likely to contain the page number data you want to eliminate. Note that .*? will match the minimum number of arbitrary characters, ensuring the that the  in the match is paired with the same leading . – AFH 12 hours ago

I would also like to thank @alzaj for providing the right direction, as well. 
Thanks a lot! Saved my day and effort!
Regards,
Aman Mittal

Answer (score 1):

escape the square brackets and use the digit-shorthand ("/d") followed by repetition sign "+" to match the page numbers:

```
<span class="pagenum"><a name="Page_\d+" id="Page_\d+">\[Pg \d+\]</a></span>
```

you can validate the above regex on following sample code:

```
placeholdertext<span class="pagenum"><a name="Page_4" id="Page_4">[Pg 4]</a></span>placeholdertext
placeholdertext
<span class="pagenum"><a name="Page_111" id="Page_111">[Pg 111]</a></span>
placeholdertext<span class="pagenum"><a name="Page_222" id="Page_222">[Pg 222]</a></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out the time and providing a solution. It is specific to Page_1 and does not work for Pg_1 but we can always tweak the regex. Thanks a lot for all the help. You solution has been of great help. I am too grateful to you. Thanks a lot! Stay blessed!

Comment: You're welcome! One more advantage of the @AFH solution: his regex match if there is a line break inside the span tag (checkbox "dot matches newline" in Notepad++). But the solution of AFH could also have a drawback if your span tag would contain a nested span tag.

Comment: @alzaj - I have never seen nested `<span>` tags and, though allowed, they are very unlikely in page numbering unless the page number is the innermost, which will not affect my match string. I should have mentioned checking _`. matches newline`_: thanks pointing that out.

Comment: @alzaj -  I am sorry to trouble you again. But in my project, I cam across another type of page number span: <span class="tei tei-pb" id="page001">[pg 001]</span><a name="Pg001" id="Pg001" class="tei tei-anchor"></a> I tried this code to find them all at once: <span class="tei tei-pb" id="page\d+">[pg \d+]</span><a name="Pg\d+" id="Pg\d+" class="tei tei-anchor"></a> However, it does not seem to work. Could you please let me know the errors in the regex search? I would be highly obliged to you

Comment: Also, If I would like to search for roman number - i, ii, iii... in the same regex then how would I go about it?

Comment: @AFH Request you to help me out once more, if possible. Would greatly appreciate your valuable time and expertise.

Comment: Using [this site](https://regex101.com/) I was able to see that the problem is the square brackets, which need to be escaped to be matched literally (`\[` and `\]`); otherwise, they are treated as delimiting a character set in a single character match. Note that there is no exact match for NotePad++, but I was able to use the "golang" flavour. For Roman numerals you simply replace `\d+` by `.+`: it means that there is a possibility of matching non-numeric page number, but I cannot imagine that this would happen. You could tighten the criteria with `[0-9ivxdm]+`.

Comment: @AFH Thank you taking out the time and replying to the query. I am extremely grateful to you for helping me out so much. Regarding the span regex, the regex worked after including the brackets and not after removing the. Moreover, your trick `.+` worked for the roman numbers a well. To search for `<span class="tei tei-pb" id="pageix">[pg ix]</span><a name="Pgix" id="Pgix" class="tei tei-anchor"></a>` I used this regex and it worked wonders `<span class="tei tei-pb" id="page.+">\[pg .+\]</span><a name="Pg.+" id="Pg.+" class="tei tei-anchor"></a>`

Comment: @AFH Thank you so much for helping me out. Overwhelmed and grateful! May you always stay blessed and happy!